# What is the difference between an Alphabet and an element of a set?

Tags: finite-automata, automata, cellular-automata

What is the difference between an Alphabet and an element of a set?

Whether Alphabet is an element of a set or it is a set itself?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little more correct to say that an Alphabet is a *domain*, whose definition consists of: "a set."  In other words, an Alphabet is the set of all *possible* letters, such that any symbol that is *not* within that set, is not "a letter."

Notice that "a word" is *not* "a set," but rather "a collection" of "letters," because any word (such as the word, "letters") might contain the same letter many times.

Answer (score 0):

if we only talk about automata theory, an Alphabet is a set of elements(letters). 
So an Alphabet is an example of set where elements of this set are letters.

For exemple an alphabet A = {a, b, c} where 'a' is one of its elements.

I don't know if it is the answer you want. Maybe you could precise your question if it is not ? :)

EDIT : But you can have a set of sets like :

K = { {a, b, c}, {m, n, o} } which contains two Alphabets. But here K isn't an Alphabet anymore, it's a set of Alphabet.

Bye.